# Render PDF using blob in Angular blocked by Chrome ad-block

Tags: angular, typescript, adblock

My setup is the following:

```
getDocumentPdf(name: string) {
this.pdfService.getPdfFile(name).subscribe((data) => {
  const file = new Blob([data], {type:'application/pdf'});
  const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  window.open(fileUrl);
});
```

}

and pdfService is :

```
getPdfFile(name: string) {
    const url = environment.apiUrl + '/files/';
    const httpOpt = {
        'responseType': 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
    };

    return this.http.get<any>(url + name, httpOpt);
}
```

When using chrome the popup is blocked. Using incognito solves the problem but i want users to access it using standard browser.

Kind regards,